# Using Android's C2DM with market disabled

Tags: android, google-play

I am developing an Android app as a research tool. The idea behind is that a researcher hands out a couple of Android device to participants and they use the device to gather data on behalf of the researcher.

Now I would like to make use of Android's C2DM (cloud to device messaging). The problem here is that a Google account is required. This is not going to work for me since the researcher would have to pre-configure one account for each device. That would be feasible but the actual problem arises from the Market access. Participants could use that account to buy anything from the Market. So my question is how to limit the Market's functionality to just free apps while maintaining C2DM.

Thanks everyone

Comment: You need a google checkout account to buy apps from the market. Just don't put a credit card in for the google account...

Comment: Sounds like a plan. That's probably it. Thx a million

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot "limit the Market's functionality to just free apps".

You could seek an alternative solution for your problem, other than C2DM. There are third party options, such as Urban Airship, that probably do not require Google accounts.

Or, you could root the devices and try to remove the Market application entirely, along with any other application that might depend on that account (e.g., Gmail, Dialtacts). However, there is a decent chance that you will miss something.

Comment: Removing the market entirely is not an option. I was thinking what happens when you try to purchase something from the market and did't give your credit card to Google? But I'll also check out Urban Airship and MQTT. Thx

Comment: Urban Airship uses C2DM so that won't help at all!

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to root the devices and block access to the market address - C2DM would continue to function but the market itself would cease to function.